# Proving that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^n)=\text{PGL}(n+1,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, automorphism-group

Consider $\mathbb{P}^n$ as an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$. I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

> Prove that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^n)=\text{PGL}(n+1,\mathbb{C})$
>
> [hint: prove that automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^n$ send hyperplanes into hyperplanes]

Let $H:=Z(L)$ be a hyperplane, where $L$ is a linear form. I've noticed that if $f\in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^n)$, then $f^{-1}(H)=Z(L\circ f)$. Taking a representation $f=(F_0:...:F_n)$ with $F_i$'s homogeneous of same degree $d$, then $L\circ f$ gives us a polynomial of degree $d$.

If $H=Z(x_i)$, and assuming the claim from the hint, then $Z(x_i\circ f)=Z(F_i)$ is a hyperplane, i.e., $d=\deg(F_i)=1$. Since the $F_i$'s can be rescaled by a non-zero constant, then $f\in\text{PGL}(n+1,\mathbb{C})$.

Now I can't see any intuitive reason why the claim should be true. I'm sure it must be some very particular feature of $\mathbb{P}^n$, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Sorry, marked this as a duplicate of the wrong question the first time around. This is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150605/classification-of-automorphisms-of-projective-space/150614 and should be marked as such.

Comment: @KReiser, I'm not familiar with schemes, bundles etc, so the post you mentioned doesn't help me, unfortunately

Comment: You don't need any knowledge of schemes for this one - just what an invertible sheaf is. Do you know that?

Comment: Do you have access to Bézout’s Theorem?